# Время выполнения алгоритма?

Tags: алгоритм, сложность, асимптотика

Есть алгоритм динамического программирования где нужно найти наибольшую уменьшающуюся подпоследовательность. Алгоритм в данном случае не важен, не могу определится  с временем выполнения вот этой основной части этого поиска

```
        int[] T = new int[7];  ///массив для поиска подпоследовательности 
        int n = T.Length; ///длина массива

        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < i; j++)
            {
                // работаем с T за O(1)
            }
        }
```

Если бы второй for пробегался от 1 до n то ясно что время выполнения n2(n квадрат), но в приведенном выше случае получается что? n log(n) ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Смотрите. Первый внутренний цикл имеет длину 1, второй — 2, третий — 3, ..., последний — `(n - 2)`.

Сумма арифметической прогрессии сворачивается:

```
1 + 2 + ... + (n - 2) = (1 + (n - 2)) * (n - 2) / 2 = n^2/2 - 3n/2 + 1
```

Если нужна `O`-асимптотика, получается `O(n^2)`.

То же на пальцах: из квадрата `n × n` вы пробегаете лишь верхний (или нижний, смотря как индексировать) треугольник, то есть пол-квадрата. Весь квадрат `O(n^2)`, его половина тоже.

Comment: "Весь квадрат O(n^2), его половина тоже."

Вот это меня постоянно и сбивает...

Comment: @koks_rs: Угу, и правда несколько неинтуитивно. Константы в реальности тоже важны: например, маленькие массивы быстрее сортирует insertion sort, чем quicksort, хотя его асимптотика и хуже. Но при больших `n` асимптотика обычно побеждает.

Comment: @koks_rs, площадь, она и есть площадь. Изменяется она пропорционально квадрату изменения линейного измерения фигуры.

Вспомните из школьной геометрии площадь треугольника, круга и т.д.

Answer (score 3):

вот почитайте, крайне полезно.

[Введение в анализ сложности алгоритмов (часть 1)](http://habrahabr.ru/post/196560/)

[Введение в анализ сложности алгоритмов (часть 2)](http://habrahabr.ru/post/195482/)

[Введение в анализ сложности алгоритмов (часть 3)](http://habrahabr.ru/post/195996/)

[Введение в анализ сложности алгоритмов (часть 4)](http://habrahabr.ru/post/196226/)