# Почему для вычисления сложности алгоритмов используется log N вместо lb N?

Tags: алгоритм, математика, сложность

Во всех источниках сложность алгоритмов обозначается как log N (без указания основания). При этом имеется в виду логарифм по основанию 2.

Но для такого логарифма есть свое обозначение [lb](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC). Причем это обозначение стандартизировано [ISO 31-11](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) и наверное было бы логичнее и правильнее пользоваться именно им, но этого по какой-то причине не просходит, почему?

**UPD: у меня нет никакого математического образования и все, что я знаю о логарифмах, что это действие обратное возведению в степень.**

Возьмем конкретный пример - бинарный поиск. Везде описывают его сложность как *log N*. При этом под *log N*, как мне кажется, все таки подразумевается логарифм N по основанию именно 2, т.к. количество операций составляет именно логарифм N по основанию 2, т.е. в какую степень надо возвести именно 2 (а не 10 и не 100), чтобы получить N. Поэтому, если честно, я не понимаю ответов типа *"потому что постоянные коэффициенты в обозначении *O(n)* не имеют значения"* или *"так как запись с большим O на константы не реагирует - неважно, какой именно логарифм использовать..."* и буду признателен за более развернутый ответ, написанный не для математиков. Разве правило, что "константы в О-большом не имеют значения", относится к основанию логарифма? Разве для бинарного поиска не имеет никакой разницы как записать его сложность - логарифмом по основанию 2 или по основанию 100?

Если под *log N* для бинарного поиска подразумевается именно логарифм по основанию 2, то почему бы его не записать как *lb N*, раз уж для двоичного логарифма есть свое обозначение, вместо того, чтобы записывать вообще без указания основания?

**UPD 2:** я понимаю что *"O(N) - это ни в коем случае не количество сравнений, это оценка времени работы алгоритма, максимально отвязанная от деталей реализации и машины."*

Но вот этого: *"А так как запись с большим O на константы не реагирует - неважно, какой именно логарифм использовать..."* я не понимаю. Почему не важно какой логарифм использовать? Вот графики трех логарифмов - двоичного, натурального и по основанию 0,5:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возьмем все тот же бинарный поиск. Разве мы можем заменить в его сложности основание у логарифма с два на десять? А с два на 0,5? Мне кажется, не можем. Т.е. мы не можем подставить в выражении log N произвольное основание потому что зависимость будет совершенно другая - это хорошо видно на графике. Т.о. какой именно логарифм использовать важно. Или я не прав?

Comment: вам будет проще понять если вы построите график отношения `log_2(x)/ln(x)` и убедитесь, что это константа. Потом прочите ещё раз определение (`f(x) = O(log x)` ->  `0 <= f(x) <= C log(x)` для больших `x`, где `C` это константа, которая не зависит от `x`). Изменяя основание логарифмы, вы можете значение `C` изменить, но на само соотношение `f(x) = O(log x)` это никак не влияет  -- не важно чему C равно).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Поскольку все логарифмы одинаковы с точностью до константы :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А так как запись с большим O на константы не реагирует - неважно, какой именно логарифм использовать...

**Update** на ваше обновление вопроса.

Смысл не в конкретном количестве сравнений, а в том, как растет это количество (а значит, и *время* работы) с ростом N. Это ни в коем случае не конкретное количество тех или иных операций! То, что некоторый алгоритм имеет сложность *O(g(N))* всего лишь означает, что если мы путем экспериментов будем строить некую функцию зависимости времени работы алгоритма от N и получим некую *f(N)*, то сможем найти некоторые такие константные *c* и *N<sub>0</sub>*, что для всех *N>=N<sub>0</sub>* будет выполняться неравенство *0 <= f(N) <= cg(N)*. Это - определение записи с большим О.

Еще раз - O(N) - это ни в коем случае не количество сравнений, это оценка времени работы алгоритма, максимально отвязанная от деталей реализации и машины.

**Update 2**

Я реализую алгоритм бинарного поиска и при этом ужасно туплю, так что вместо одного сравнения я делаю их 20. Вы делаете их ровно столько, сколько нужно. Но и ваша, и моя реализации будут работать время O(log N) - пусть моя и будет работать в 100 раз медленнее вашей. Потому что и моя, и ваша реализации при возрастании N в 100 раз будут работать дольше **на** некоторое время - пусть и у каждого свое, скажем, у вас на минуту, у меня - на час. Главное, что вид зависимости будет одинаков - при увеличении в сколько-то раз рост будет на сколько-то.

И, кстати, у вас зависимости *log<sub>2</sub>x* и *ln x* как раз одинаковы - стоит только немного изменить масштаб по оси *y*. Что до логарифма по основанию, меньшему 1 - ну, как говорится, не стоит утрировать. Но и тут - достаточно взять его по модулю или отрицательную константу :)

Кстати, посмотрите несколько ссылок [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/267481/195342).

Comment: О-большое говорит, что для достаточно больших N рост времени работы не быстрее указанной функции (предел отношения меньше константы).

Comment: @jfs Предел отношения **не больше** константы. Кстати, определение взято из "Алгоритмов" Кормена и иже с ним.

Comment: какая разница между "меньше" (<) и "не больше" (<=) если константа не фиксированна? К тому же я не пытался буква в букву определение из какого-то учебника дать, а обозначить как можно думать о big-O (ограничение на рост при большом вводе)

Comment: Потому что ваше "меньше константы" автоматически дает (в смысле O-обозначений) что-то, стремящееся к нулю...

Comment: нет, конечно. Это просто значит что отношение меньше бесконечности (ничего не говорит о стремлении к нулю).   Подумайте: если у вас: f(x)<=C g(x) для больших x, тогда f(x) < 2C g(x) (увеличили правую положительную часть)¶ Ещё раз: у вас слишком сухой язык и более простой взгляд: «big-O определяет ограничение на рост при большом вводе» — не повредит в качестве комментария к ответу.

Comment: В виду того, что в ответе акцентируется внимание на связи О-большого с временем работы алгоритма, то также заметил бы что О-большое также иногда используется и для оценки дополнительной памяти под временное хранение данных, которые необходимы для работы алгоритма.

Comment: Хороший ответ, но я все равно поддерживаю @jfs в разрезе его первого комментария - я хоть и имею, именно, математическое высшее образование, но для краткого ответа использовал бы именно такую формулировку, а затем добавил её детальное пояснение по необходимости, т.к. в него нужно еще вникать (человеку со стороны, не имеющему достаточной мат. базы такое, скорее всего, тяжело дается), а для понимания без углубления в детали (обычно человек именно такого и ожидает) достаточно было именно такого.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, я нашел ответ на свой изначальный вопрос:

*"Во всех источниках сложность алгоритмов обозначается как log N (без указания основания). При этом имеется в виду логарифм по основанию 2.
Но для такого логарифма есть свое обозначение lb. Причем это обозначение стандартизировано ISO 31-11 и наверное было бы логичнее и правильнее пользоваться именно им, но этого по какой-то причине не просходит, почему?"*

вот здесь:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Particular_bases

т.е. например, в информатике log N используется вместо lb N или log N по конкретному основанию, **потому что основание логарифма понятно из контекста**.

Возможно, основание логарифма вообще значения не имеет, когда речь идет об О-большое, как ответил @Harry. Но, если честно, моих математических знаний на данный момент не хватает, чтобы дать этому утверждению оценку. Поэтому я предпочту пока более общую формулировку про то, что "основание определено контекстом"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD: **Набрел в одной книг по алгоритмам (как раз в разделе бинарного поиска) на фразу: "Is it log base 2, log base 10, or the natural log?
In the above example, log base 2 applies. However, since Big O notation only concerns itself with the shape of the performance the actual base doesn't matter."** Так что, да, похоже основание логарифма не важно )

Comment: О-нотация пришла из матанализа, поэтому используется логарифм в математическом смысле - не двоичный, не десятичный, а натуральный, см. [«O» большое и «o» малое](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%ABO%C2%BB_%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%C2%ABo%C2%BB_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B5)